# where can one see columns from the world trade center?

Tags: new-york-city, where-on-earth

The [Texas State Cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_State_Cemetery) has one:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_State_Cemetery#/media/File:Texas_State_Cemetery_September_11_Memorial.jpg

The [National Atomic Testing Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Atomic_Testing_Museum) has one as well:

http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/national-atomic-testing-museum-las-vegas?select=niex2U6LrzZXh0VocG0USA

Obviously the [National September 11 Memorial & Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_September_11_Memorial_%26_Museum) has some, but, none-the-less, it makes me wonder...  who else has them?

Comment: Pieces of the WTC have made it all over the world. I think such a list is going to be monstrous, and a bit too broad for our format. A good starting point might be [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorials_and_services_for_the_September_11_attacks) though. And the largest single piece is probably [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_New_York_(LPD-21)).